# Balance is not showing

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<table width="50%" border="2" bordercolor="green">
    <tr>
        <th>ItemName</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
      <?php
      if($qw="select DISTINCT(itemname) from details where DATE(date)<='$date' order by date desc"){
      $qq = mysqli_query($con,$qw);
      while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($qq,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
      {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r['itemname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['balance']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
      }
      }
      ?>
      </table>
```

The given code is fetch product itemname but Balance is not fetch from the database.

Comment: because you don't select 'balance' in your sql.

Comment: `SELECT  DISTINCT(itemname), balance...`

Comment: select DISTINCT(itemname), balance from details where DATE(date)<='$date' order by date desc

Comment: what is the name of column which holds balance?

Comment: Can you add current output and expected output in question

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not include the 'balance' field.
Change your query to include it:

```
select DISTINCT itemname, balance from details where ...
```

Comment: The query what i m writing is this if($qw="select DISTINCT(itemname), total from details where DATE(date)<='$date' order by date desc")

Comment: <table width="50%" border="2" bordercolor="green">
 <tr>
  <th>ItemName</th>
  <th>Balance</th>
 </tr>
   <?php
   if($qw="select DISTINCT(itemname), total from details where DATE(date)<='$date' order by date desc"){
   $qq = mysqli_query($con,$qw);
   while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($qq,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
   {
     ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $r['itemname']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $r['total']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
   }
   }
   ?>
   </table>

Comment: The DISTINCT is not a function, your syntax is wrong. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html Your code should be like this: `if($qw="select DISTINCT itemname, total from details where DATE(date)<='$date' order by date desc")`

Comment: Sir, I want to show the closing balance of every item according to the date. your code is showing all entries on that particular date & i want to show the final balance of particular item